# How to make a fixed sidebar with content that stops at footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im trying to make my sidebar content follow the scrolling but stop at the footer. Currently, any content i place goes too far and overlaps the footer.

```
<div class="row row-no-padding">

   <div class="col-lg-8">
      Content is here.
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-4">
      Sidebar content would be here. I want all content here to follow my scrolling
      but stop if if i go too far(stop at the footer).
   </div>

</div>
```

Please help me with this. I know this is a minimalist example but i've tried so many combinations at this point that i dont know what the hell to write.

I've tried position:fixed but it makes the content overlap the footer. position:sticky doesnt do anything, or im not using it properly.

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: you can use position sticky, but it will be very good if you give us more html + css code